# Is it possible to give 'person A' read/write access and 'Person B' read only access

Tags: linux, unix, file-permissions

Can this be done using the owner/group/other model?

If so:

Who would be the owner of the file?

Who would be in the group for the file? would it be the both A and B ?

What would their ( A and B ) permissions be?

What would the 'other' permissions be?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Try unix.stackexchange.com, not a programming question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Can this be done using the owner / group / other model ?

It's `definitely possible` and is very basic stuff. So, you should [learn this](https://www.tecmint.com/manage-users-and-groups-in-linux/). Regardless I will answer your question.

#### What would their ( A and B ) permissions be ?

According to you, Person A should have `read/write` access but Person B should have `Read-Only`. So,

```
Permissions for A = Read + Write = 4 + 2 = 6
Permissions for B = Read Only    = 4     = 4
```

#### Who would be owner / group for the file ? would it be the both A & B ?

Depends on who you make the Owner and who you keep in the group.
Considering the role played by A and B, you can encode the permission triad further in this way.

```
If A is Owner , B is in Group            Permissions = 640
```

that means 6 for A who is Owner and 4 for B who is in group and 0 for others. Similarly

```
If B is Owner , A is in Group            Permissions = 460
```

Now You can by own create all rest of possible permutations.

#### What would the 'other' permissions be ?

If that means `Others` entity in the permission triad, then again it depends what permissions you want to give. It's `4 for Read` , `2 for Write` and `1 for execute`.

And then last number in the permission triad ( that corresponds to permissions of others ) would be sum of all permissions you give.

#### Applying permissions using `chmod`

`chmod` command changes the mods for the files in linux system that means changing permissions for owner, group and others.

```
chmod 640 sjackson
```

Here Owner can `Read + Write = 4 + 2 = 6` the file `sjackson` but the group can `Read only = 4` the file where any other can just do nothing.

Another example :

```
chmod 777 helloworld
```

Here Owner, Group and Others can do everything `R(4) + W(2) + E(1)`. That means everything on file `helloworld`

Comment: Hey @samjackson , do learn all stuffs from the link I gave in the answer. It's really useful.